# SAP NetWeaver Application Server installation hangs

Tags: installation, sap-basis, netweaver

I am trying to install SAP NetWeaver Application Server on windows 2008 R2 inside virtual box.

In one moment installation stop to advance. There is about 40 minutes and nothing happens.

Here is an install screenshot and nothing changed during the last 40 minutes - 1 hour approximately:

[EDIT: image link is broken] [image: install screenshot]

I have checked log files (Windows event log) and I didn't notice any error.

Windows host name is vtwin2008, so no space and strange chars. I have assigned 120 GB disk and 2 GB RAM.

Any suggestion how to solve the problem and continue with installation?

Comment: Another try. Now with 4GB RAM and 4 processors. The same: http://i.imgur.com/pXO05fN.png

Comment: check the sapinst log files: http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/MaxDB/Problems+during+installation,+upgrade+or+migration